# Pulling particular data from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, substring, indexof, jwt

Currently, I am using substring() and lastIndexOf() to extract the data I need from a given JSON object. However, sometimes the JSON object's order of the data changes and as such messes up the data I retrieve.

I am looking for a more exact and precise solution of pulling example@live.com and ExampleName both without quotes from a given jwt token as seen below through the use of whatever it may be to accomplish it. Thank you.

```
{"user":{"_id":"5ec0e2d36851fcd7ab20a0fe","email":"example@live.com","name":"ExampleName","highScore":0},"iat":1592025639,"exp":1592025939}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you use substring? Your token is string? Then just convert it to object and read its properties

```
const obj = JSON.parse(yourToken)
const { name, email } = obj
```